# php script to get data from csv to blog website

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, post

I am trying to write a basic blog that i can post blogs and view them blogs. I have posted the blog by form action however what i want to try to do now is that get the data that i got from my csv into h1 h2 p2 on my viewpost.html. How would i be able to do this.
This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Blog</title>
<link type='text/css' rel ='stylesheet' href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<form action="form_process.php" method="post">
<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" id='title'/>
<label for="desc">Description</label>
<input type="text" name="desc" id='desc'/>
<label for="cont">Content</label>
<input type="text" name="cont" id='cont'/>
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

This is form_process.php

```
<?php
        if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
        {
            $errorMessage = "";

            if(empty($_POST['title']))
            {
                $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a title!</li>";
            }
            if(empty($_POST['desc']))
            {
                $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a description!</li>";
            }
            if(empty($_POST['cont']))
            {
                $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a description!</li>";
            }

            $varTitle = $_POST['title'];
            $varDesc = $_POST['desc'];
            $varCont = $_POST['cont'];

            if(empty($errorMessage)) 
            {
                $fs = fopen("mydata.csv","a");
                fwrite($fs,$varTitle . ", " .$varDesc . ", " .$varCont . "\n");
                fclose($fs);

                header("Location: index.html");
                exit;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

And lastly this is my viewpost.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> View Post</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="post">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should avoid csv for your database, its good for export/import but lacks search or picking out single row etc. Use a real database or if you want it flat file, use json instead as its easy to encode/decode to array and php has a bunch or array functions which will make working on the data much easier. Though your still have problems with memory using flatfile approach.

Comment: or how can i use json php to sort the data it seems better

Comment: your use [json_decode(str, true)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode the json into an array, then you can use [array sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).